# display data from my database using dataGridView?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I want to display data from my database using dataGridView, but I am not getting the desired result. It's showing blank spaces in the table when I run the code.
Here is the code:

```
     MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, ca.getConnection());
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;                  
     MySqlDataAdapter MyAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);               
     DataSet dSet = new DataSet();                        
     MyAdapter.Fill(dSet);                                       
     dataGridView1.DataSource = dSet.Tables[0];
```

Comment: what is the expected result and what is the issue with current code? have you debug and check the data you fetch as dSet.Tables[0]?

Comment: I want to display the contents of my database in the table but it's showing blank spaces in all the columns when i run the code.

Comment: have you add columns to your dataGridView1 from designer view?

Comment: yes, I have done all the necessary things in the designer.

Comment: @ReeshabhKaran are you talking abour windows-desktop app or web apps?

Comment: windows-desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't clearly specifies what exactly the required desired result or the problem is occurring. But try providing the DataMember property of the DataGridView like in this code below-

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=pubs;Integrated Security=True";
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Authors";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
connection.Open();
dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Authors_table");
connection.Close();
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataMember = "Authors_table";
```

Comment: I don't think Datagridview required bind .. op is talking about windows/desktop app not web based app.  its a datagridview not gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last line of your code with this code may be this will be helpful once i had a same problem like your one. But my problem resolved after using this.

dataGridView1.ItemSource = dSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;

Answer (score 0):

Hey listen i am retrieving data from database and i am using below code its working fine..Its SQLSERVER code. But you could get help for MYSQL from this.

```
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\librarydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
        con.Open();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from student", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: The problem still persists.